# Codeigniter sending out multiple emails

Tags: codeigniter, email, expressionengine

I am using codeigniters email class inside an Expression Engine plugin (EE runs off CI). 
For some reason each time the plugin is run it sends out 2 emails, instead of 1. The emails are identical.

```
{exp:cdwd_emailer:questionnaire type="{segment_3}" entry_id="{segment_4}"}
```

Here is the function being called by the above.

```
public function questionnaire() {

    $type = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('type');
    $typeLower = str_replace("-", " ", $type);
    $typeUpper = ucwords($typeLower);

    print_r($type);

    $entry_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');

    $subject = $typeUpper.' Questionnaire Submission';
    $fromEmail = 'email@email.com';
    $fromName = 'Test Name';
    $toEmail = 'email@email.com';

    $message = '
        <p>A new '.$typeLower.' has been submitted.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.domain.co.uk/questionnaires/view/'.$type.'/'.$entry_id.'">Please click here to view this submission</a></p>
    ';

    $this->EE->load->library('email');
    $this->EE->email->set_mailtype("html");         
    $this->EE->email->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $this->EE->email->to($toEmail);     
    $this->EE->email->subject($subject);
    $this->EE->email->message($message);
    $this->EE->email->send();

}
```

Can anyone tell me why? I can't figure it out. I printed out the contents of the type and entry_id params to check only 1 of each are being collected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to clear you email object after sending mail.
As per Expression Engine, you have to call:

```
 ee()->email->clear();
```

For your case:

```
$this->EE->email->clear();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added it in, but its still sending two emails.

Comment: Stop execution (`exit();`) after email send code. Then check your mail.

Comment: When I add exit() it still sends two emails, but also shows a blank page instead of the template.

Comment: then you have to check in your server email queue.